# Jqxgrid not showing up

Tags: javascript, json, jqwidget

Jqxgrid is not getting displayed.

When I open it in the Chrome and inspect it, it shows an error saying:

> Uncaught Typeerror : #(...).jqxgrid is not a function.

I have searched for the error but none of the solutions helped. I am loading data from a servlet in json array form.

Following is the javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myarray = new Array();
    vUrlStr = 'SERVLTGrid';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: vUrlStr,
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, data)
            {
                var row = {};
                row["ref_no"] = new String(data.ref_no);
                row["ref_name"] = new String(data.ref_name);
                row["date_col"] = new String(data.date_issued);
                row["doc_name"] = new String(data.max_credit);
                row["max_credit"] = new String(data.val_period);
                row["val"] = new String(data.treat_needed);
                row["latest_start"] = new String(data.late_start);
                row["treat_need"] = new String(data.doc_name);
                row["ref_date"] = new String(data.ref_date);
                myarray[i] = row;
            });
        },
        error: function (e, ts, et) {
            alert("error" + ts + et);
        }
    });
    var source = {
        localdata: myarray,
        datafields: [
            {
                name: 'ref_no',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'ref_name',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'date_col',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'doc_name',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'max_credit',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'val',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'latest_start',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'treat_need',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'ref_date',
                type: 'string'
            }
        ],
        datatype: "array"
    };
    //var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
        width: 500,
        source: source,
        columnsresize: true,
        pageable: true,
        autoheight: true,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        altrows: true,
        enabletooltips: true,
        autoshowfiltericon: true,
        editable: true,
        selectionmode: 'singlerow',
        columns: [
            {
                text: 'Reference No.',
                datafield: 'ref_no',
                editable: false,
                width: 50
            },
            {
                text: 'Referral Hospital',
                datafield: 'ref_name',
                editable: false,
                width: 100
            },
            {
                text: 'Date issued',
                datafield: 'date_col',
                editable: false,
                hidden: true,
                width: 50
            },
            {
                text: 'Doctors Name',
                datafield: 'doc_name',
                hidden: true,
                editable: false,
                width: 50
            },
            {
                text: 'Maximum Credit, Rs.',
                hidden: true,
                datafield: 'max_credit',
                editable: false,
                width: 50
            },
            {
                text: 'Validation Period',
                hidden: true,
                datafield: 'val',
                editable: false,
                width: 50
            },
            {
                text: 'Latest Start by',
                datafield: 'latest_start',
                editable: false,
                width: 50
            },
            {
                text: 'Treatment Needed',
                hidden: true,
                datafield: 'treat_need',
                editable: false,
                width: 50
            },
            {
                text: 'Referral Date',
                hidden: true,
                datafield: 'ref_date',
                editable: false,
                width: 50
             }
        ]
    });
});
```

Here are the script tags used:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.pager.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxdata.export.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.edit.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.export.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have to "include" `jqxgrid.js` in your `script` tags.

Comment: All the scripts have been included. Still doesn't help. Will post all the javascripts added if required

Comment: Please share your HTML, please, JS is not enough. And what about jQuery ?

Comment: script tags added :)

Comment: And in the `network` tab of the developer console of your browser, nothing is not found ?

Comment: What is supposed to be present? I do get some time durations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113913/discussion-between-adrenaline-dj-and-doubtful).

Comment: I need immediate help, somebody please respond

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to clean the `datafields` array, the `columns` array from jqxGrid declaration and the JSON, to make these 3 items to have the same keys and avoiding a painful conversion when data is received.

The `name` of a `datafield` (`datafields` array of a `source`) must match the `datafield` of a `column` (`columns` array of the `jqxGrid` settings) and must match with a property name in the JSON data.

All the needed JS files from jQWidgets are included. You can see it in the JS properties of the Pen (the wheel in the top left ocrner of the JS panel).

So, here is a working exmaple on CodePen: http://codepen.io/adrenalinedj/pen/zBvYLb

And here the JSON used for exmaple base don what you shared in the chat we made:
http://codepen.io/adrenalinedj/pen/mEedGr

Comment: Found something interesting! If I run my own code with your URL, it works! So you think it is a problem with JSON object returned?

Comment: It's a beginning of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Uncaught Typeerror : #(...).jqxgrid is not a function will be raised when you use jqxgrid instead of jqxGrid because jqxgrid is not a function, jqxGrid is. Also your data binding is incorrect. You should bind it to adapter but you commented out that code.